# Java Counting Coins Code showing error after debugging

Tags: java, integer, double

I'm having trouble with my counting coins code, which takes user input of how many coins they have and converts them into dollar amount. I keep getting an error code and am somewhat confused as to how to put this together. Can you help?

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountChangeWithScanner{
 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int quarters; //number of quarters that the user inputs.
        int dimes; //number of dimes that the user inputs
        int nickels; //number of nickels that the user inputs
        int pennies; //number of pennies that the user inputs

        Scanner stdio = new Scanner(System.in); // record user input 

        double dollars; // total value of coins

        /* Prompt user to enter the number of each type of coin */

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of quarters  */

        System.out.print("Enter the number of quarters:  ");
        quarters = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of dimes */
        System.out.print("Enter the number of dimes:  ");
        dimes = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of nickels */
        System.out.print("Enter the number of nickels:  ");
        nickels = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of pennies */
        System.out.print("Enter the number of pennies:  ");
        pennies = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        dollars = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("The total in dollars is $");
        System.out.println(dollars);
        System.out.println("");

 


    }
}
```

---

Comment: Which "error code" ? A quarter is the same as a dime or as a penny?

Comment: @lucumt Lower types can be converted to higher types implicitly.

Josh, It would help to add the error you're getting.

Comment: Your formula for converting quarters, dimes, and nickels to dollars is incorrect.  You have to multiply the number of quarters times 25, the number of dimes times 10, and the number of nickels times 5.  The result is in pennies, so you have to divide the sum by 100.0 to get dollars.

Comment: I understand that I would have to multiply it, I just don't know where to add that multiplication. I've been getting the error code of "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: " for lines 16, 14, and 30.

Answer (score 0):

Josh if you are having the calculation issue, maybe try this solution. Let me know if it helped.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountChangeWithScanner{
 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int quarters; //number of quarters that the user inputs.
        int dimes; //number of dimes that the user inputs
        int nickels; //number of nickels that the user inputs
        int pennies; //number of pennies that the user inputs

        Scanner stdio = new Scanner(System.in); // record user input 

        double dollars; // total value of coins

        /* Prompt user to enter the number of each type of coin */

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of quarters  */

        System.out.print("Enter the number of quarters:  ");
        quarters = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of dimes */
        System.out.print("Enter the number of dimes:  ");
        dimes = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of nickels */
        System.out.print("Enter the number of nickels:  ");
        nickels = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of pennies */
        System.out.print("Enter the number of pennies:  ");
        pennies = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        /* Calculate the total value of the coins */
        dollar = (quarters * 0.25) + (dimes * 0.10) + (nickels * 0.05) + (pennies * 0.01);

        /* Print the total value of the coins */
        System.out.println("The total value of the coins is: " + dollar);
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying out this I got the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

        at CountChangeWithScanner.main(Change counter.java:14)

Comment: I also seem to be getting the following error aswell 

"java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int
 The method printlnf(double) is undefined for the type PrintStream
"

Comment: @Josh D'Astoli: You define `double dollars` but refer to `dollar` in the last two lines.  Calculate the pennies as an `int`, then divide by 100.0 to get dollars.  Otherwise, you'll possibly get floating point rounding errors.  Money amounts should always be kept in `int` pennies and converted to dollars for display only.